# ORA2 Customization Not able to find tables

Tags: python, django, openedx

Recently I am assigned with `Openedx-ORA2` Customization. But I am not able to find the Assignment table and Question table. Like I am able to find Rubric table and criteria etc. But How is  rubric linked to questions and  where can I find assignment Id of each assignment I create .

[image]